# After installing cinnamon, left with nemo (which doesn't show a global menu)

Tags: 12.10, cinnamon, nemo

After playing a little bit with cinnamon I decided to uninstall it.

So I logged out from the cinnamon session and logged in to my unity session.
I then typed `sudo apt-get purge cinnamon*` and then enter.

Now I am stuck with nemo file manager which doesn't show a global menu at the top of the screen.

The thing is that I would like to see its preferences to test if it could work for me, but I can't.

What can I do?

I would prefer installing nautilus and then trying to install nemo without cinnamon (if that would make things better).

This is how it looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install Nautilus, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nautilus
```

You can run this command in Terminal to show the default app for folder:

```
xdg-mime query default inode/directory
```

Then do this to make Nautilus the default file manager

```
xdg-mime default nautilus.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
xdg-open $HOME
```

To install Nemo File Manager in Ubuntu by itself, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nemo
```

Install Extra plugins for Nemo File Manager, First add PPA from above then install:

```
sudo apt-get install nemo-compare nemo-dropbox nemo-fileroller nemo-pastebin nemo-seahorse nemo-share
```

<sup>Source:[Ubuntu Updates](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/gwendal_le_bihan_dev_cinnamon_stable)</sup>